# Identify drywall texture

Tags: drywall, texture

I’m having trouble figuring out how to replicate this texture. [image]

Comment: I agree with the light stopm answer from below it could have been done with a roller or a sponge, not a kitchen sponge but a large foam or natural sponge with larger irregular holes. I would lean more to the sponge because of the different angles. Load the sponge and dab and wipe after a few minutes flatten the ridges with a wide taping knife but use very light pressure or your knock down won't match (it is difficult for pros to match texture). If you don't like how it looks prior to it being totally dry you can scrape it off with the knife and try again.

Comment: Can you post a wider angle picture? It looks like a regular stomp, with a light knockdown. This was most likely done with a very light mix, and a 3/8" or lighter knap roller, then stomped with a pressed brush, prior to knockdown. It may have even been lightly scraped prior to painting.

Comment: Is the purpose to replicate the texture on a large area or to repair and match a small area?  There are different solutions for the two cases.

Answer (score 2):

That looks almost like a stomp texture with a circular or tree bark like mix or even a light knockdown.
[Here is a sample of a few different textures](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/563d6063e4b081a4bb97ee20/t/566e3f094bf118e6b454e049/1450065722974/?format=1500w).

Answer (score 1):

this texture was done by hand and only the creator knows how to duplicate it exactly. give your ceiling your own custom brocade.  skim coat your ceiling with joint compound. either thin down all purpose with a small amount if water and mix it to a cake frosting consistency, or use top coating compound. just mix it until its smooth and fluffy. spread it over the surface in sections about 8x8 feet, and use a hawk to create the brocade. just push it up into the wet compound and pull it off, creating peaks that hang down. let it sit for 10 minutes. while you are waiting spread the next section and use the hock. spin it around or give it a 1/4 turn while pulling it down. then with very light it no pressure, drag a knockdown knife or 18" taping knife across the ceiling to create the knockdown effect. it will give your room an excellent personal touch you can brag about.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the great answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use sponge.

Comment: This is interesting, but we prefer answers that are more than one sentence long, and have some supporting info. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.